# Convert single column into three comma separated columns using awk

Tags: awk

I have a single long column and want to reformat it into three comma separated columns, as indicated below, using `awk` or any Unix tool.

**Input:**

```
Xaa
Ybb
Mdd
Tmmn
UUnx
THM
THSS
THEY
DDe
```

**Output:**

```
Xaa,Ybb,Mdd
Tmmn,UUnx,THM
THSS,THEY,DDe
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,NR%3?",":"\n";}' file
Xaa,Ybb,Mdd
Tmmn,UUnx,THM
THSS,THEY,DDe
```

#### How it works

For every line of input, this prints the line followed by, depending on the line number, either a comma or a newline.

The key part is this ternary statement:

```
NR%3?",":"\n"
```

This takes the line number modulo 3.  If that is non-zero, then it returns a comma.  If it is zero, it returns a newline character.

#### Handling files that end before the final line is complete

The assumes that the number of lines in the file is an integer multiple of three.  If it isn't, then we probably want to assure that the last line has a newline.  This can be done, as Jonathan Leffler suggests, using:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,NR%3?",":"\n";} END { if (NR%3 != 0) print ""}' file
```

If the final line is short of three columns, the above code will leave a trailing comma on the line.  This may or may not be a problem.  If we do not want the final comma, then use:

```
awk 'NR==1{printf "%s",$0; next} {printf "%s%s",(NR-1)%3?",":"\n",$0;} END {print ""}' file
```

Jonathan Leffler offers this slightly simpler alternative to achieve the same goal:

```
awk '{ printf("%s%s", pad, $1); pad = (NR%3 == 0) ? "\n" : "," } END { print "" }'
```

#### Improved portability

To support platforms which don't use `\n` as the line terminator, Ed Morton suggests:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{ printf("%s%s", pad, $1); pad = (NR%3?OFS:ORS)} END { print "" }' file
```

Comment: Any merit in adding `END { if (NR%3 != 0) print ""}` so that the last line at least ends with a newline if there is not a multiple of three lines in the input?  Fixing it so that you don't emit the extra trailing comma is harder (that is, you might have a last line reading `One,` or `One,Two,` if the file is not a multiple of three lines long).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good thought!  I added your suggestion to the answer.  I also added code to omit the final comma.

Comment: Funnily enough, I was experimenting just as your comment popped up, and I'd come up with: `awk '{ printf("%s%s", pad, $1); pad = (NR%3 == 0) ? "\n" : "," } END { print "" }'`.  This uses the 'uninitialized variable is treated as empty string' property.  And `print` outputs a newline always (I confused myself briefly by trying `print "\n"` which gave two newlines at the end; `printf "\n"` would work instead of `print ""`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Very good!  I added that to the answer also.

Comment: Thanks Guys , i got the answer i needed  from reading your codes .You are all awesome

Comment: This is the right approach so `+1` but a couple of points - 1) you should use `ORS` instead of `"\n"` so it'll work even on platforms/applications where the newline is `\r\n` (and it's slightly more concise), 2) An unparenthesized ternary expression will cause a syntax error in some awks in some contexts (e.g. try `print 1>2?"foo":"bar"` on OSX awk) so it's best to always parenthesize it `(NR%3?",":ORS)` or even `-v OFS=, ... (NR%3?OFS:ORS)` to avoid that issue and IMHO it improves clarity a bit when the start/end of the ternary expression is delimited like that.

Comment: @EdMorton Excellent!  Added to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool for this.  Use `pr`

```
pr -3ats,
```

3 columns width, across, suppress header, comma as separator.

Answer (score 0):

```
xargs -n3 < file | awk -v OFS="," '{$1=$1} 1'
```

`xargs` uses `echo` as default action, `$1=$1` forces rebuild of `$0`.

Using only awk I would go with this (which is similar to what proposed by @jonathan-leffler and @John1024)

```
{
     sep = NR == 1 ? ""   : \
          (NR-1)%3 ? ","  : \
                     "\n"
     printf sep $0
}

END {
     printf "\n"
}
```